# Mysql Structure for rental availability

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have to import an availability calendar of 30,000 places into MySQL, and I am stuck on structure design.  I need something which will allow me to easily subquery and join availability of checkIn for a given date.

Actually, each day has several options

- Can checkIn and CheckOut
- Not Available
- CanCheckIn only
- CanCheckOut
- OnRequest

now what would be a most optimal solution for a table?

```
PlaceId Day AvailabilityCode    ???
```

Then I would have 366 * 30, 000 rows?  I am afraid of that.

Is there any better way to do?

The xml data I should parse looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<vacancies>
<vacancy>
<code>AT1010.200.1</code>
<startday>2010-07-01</startday>
<availability>YYYNNNQQ</availability>
<changeover>CCIIOOX</changeover>
<minstay>GGGGGGGG</minstay>
<flexbooking>YYYYY</flexbooking>
</vacancy>
</vacancies>
```

Where [image: table]

---

**Crucial additional information:** The problem is that the availability calendar is given as an XML feed, and I have to import it and repopulate my database each 10-20 minutes.

Comment: you only need to add rows when something is not available. A missing row for a date and room can be implicitly interpreted as availability

Comment: Can Checkin only: that would be the Bates Motel, I suppose.

Comment: The problem is that the availability calendar is given by XML feed, and I have to pull it and repopulate in my database each 10-20 mins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the XML feed, not the table structure.  The easiest solution would be to ask the feed provider to deliver just a delta rather than a whole dump.  But presumably there's a good reason why that is not possible.

So you will have to do it.  You should store the XML feeds somehow, and compare the new file with the previous one.  This will give you the delta, which you can then apply to your database table.  There are several approaches you could take, and which you choose will largely depend on your programming prowess, and the capabilities of your database product.

For instance, MySQL has only had XML functionality since 5.1 and [it is still pretty limited](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xml-functions.html).  So if you want to preprocess the XML file you will probably have to do it outside the database.  An alternative approach would be to load the latest file into a staging table and use SQL to find and apply the differences.

Comment: could you help out me a bit with table structure? I use mysql server as a DB , and would import XML with extra script. This is not a big deal. The problem is to make a table in such a way, so that it will be easy to handle(query availability by let's say left joins) and to make the table replicable...

Answer (score 1):

you only need to add rows when something is not available. A missing row for a date and room can be implicitly interpreted as availability

Answer (score 0):

365 * 30000 is a little over 10 million records in a table with only small fields (int id, date or day, and a code, which is probably an int as well or maybe a char(1)). This is very doable in MySQL and will only become a problem if you got many reads and frequent updates to this table. If it is only updates now and then, it will not be much of a problem to have tables with 10 or 20 million records.

But maybe there's a better solution, although it may be more complex.

It sounds to me like some soort of booking programme. If so, each place will probably have seasons in which they can be booked. You can give each place a default value, or maybe even a default value per season. For instance, a place is available from march to august, and unavailable in the other months. Then, when a place is booked during the summer and it becomes unavailable, you can put that value in the table you suggested.

That way, you can check if a record exists for a given day for the requested place. If it does not exist, you check the default value in the 'places' table (30000 records), or the 'seasons' table where you got a record per season per place (maybe 2 to 4 records per place). That way you can cut the number of records down by a lot.

But remember this will not work if you got bookings for almost every day for each place. In that case, you will hardly ever need the defaults, and there will still be millions of records in the state-per-day table. Like I said before, this may not be a problem at all, but anyway you should consider whether the more complex solution will indeed help you decrease the data or not. It depends on you situation.

Comment: The problem is that I should get in XML way the availability and reupdate all  calendar each 10-15 minutes...